# How to add accordion in CKEditor jQuery Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ckeditor, jquery-ui-accordion

This is my HTML code

```
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label style="font-size:14px;" class="control-label">Roles and Responsibilities: 
        </label>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <textarea rows="4" style="width:100%;" name="detail" id="detail"></textarea>
        </div>
        <span style="color:red;font-size:12px;" id="jobmsg9"></span>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> This is the JQuery ajax part-

```
  CKEDITOR.replace('detail', {});
```

> This is CDN of CKEditor-

```
  <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.15.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

> When i am using this ckeeditor then showing below-
> [image]

> But, I want to add Accordion in this CKEditor.
> Thanks and regards

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? there is some add-ons you can use for this.

Comment: I already used except accordion from online CDN & and local from download ckeditor file but i want to integrate accordion. This is not working in my file.